# OrmLite: Building WHERE NOT around AND/OR condition

Tags: java, android, sql, ormlite

I want to express the following SQL-Query in OrmLite:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT (number1 = 0 AND number2 = 0)
```

The problem here is to wrap and AND-condition in a not-operation.

- My first assumption was to write:

  ```
  queryBuilder().
     where().not()
        .eq("number1", 0)
        .and()
        .eq("number2", 0);
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((NOT number1 = 0 ) AND number2 = 0)
  ```
- Next approach:

  ```
  queryBuilder().
     where().not()
        .eq("number1", 0)
        .and().not()
        .eq("number2", 0);
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((NOT number1 = 0 ) AND (NOT number2 = 0) )
  ```
- Finally I tried:

  ```
  queryBuilder.where()
     .not(
        where.eq(DbProperties.COLUMN_NAME_GROUP_ID, item.groupId)
           .and().eq(DbProperties.COLUMN_NAME_TASK_ID, item.taskId)
     );
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  IllegalArgumentException: NOT operation can only work with comparison SQL clauses
  ```

I also know about methods

```
and(int numClause) 
or(int numClause)
```

But OrmLite does not offer

```
not(int numClause).
```

Can someone assume another way to make the query built?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT (number1 = 0 AND number2 = 0)
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((NOT number1 = 0 ) OR (NOT number2 = 0) )
```

which, rearranging your prev query would be:

```
queryBuilder().
   where()
      .not().eq("number1", 0)
      .or()
      .not().eq("number2", 0);
```